# how to remove shared preference while ipa uninstall in IOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, preferences

I have an IOS ipa to save the login details such as user name and password via SharedPreferences thats works fine, but i need to remove all my used SharedPreferences while my ipa uninstall. How to do it?

```
SavePreferences("two", "");
LoadPreferences();
SavePreferences(String key, String value)async {
    sharedPreferences = await getSharedPreferences("TEST", MODE_PRIVATE);
   }
LoadPreferences()async{
    sharedPreferences = await getSharedPreferences("TEST", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
    String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM2", "");   
   }
```

I want to remove this SharedPreferences when my ipa uninstall.

Comment: Solution :- use of package flutter_secure_storage: ^4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

on iOS simulator, you can select from top mac tool bar "device", then choose Erase All Content and Settings.